# Unexpected wrapper element SOAP wdsl error

Tags: node.js, node-soap

Im trying to send request to a wdsl with node-soap client

here is my code :

```
var url = 'https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl';

            soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {

                var today = new Date();
                var params = {
                    terminalId: "1926577",
                    userName: "test2",
                    userPassword: "test1",
                    orderId: receipt.recieptId + "",
                    amount: parseInt(receipt.overal_price) + "",
                    localDate: today.format('ymd'),
                    localTime: today.format('His'),
                    additionalData: "Customer No: 15220",
                    callBackUrl: "http://test.ir/pay/verify",
                    payerId: parseInt(receipt.user) + ""
                };

                console.log(params);


                client.bpPayRequest(params, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    console.log(result);
                });
```

and this error returned from wsdl :

> Error: soap:Client: Unexpected wrapper element bpPayRequest found.
>   Expected {http://interfaces.core.sw.bps.com/}bpPayRequest.

It seems the ns1 is not added as a prefix to

> 

node in xml request

I updated the module to v0.13.0 and added following :

```
used this code :
var options = {
                ignoredNamespaces: {
                    namespaces: [],
                    override: true
                }
            }
```

Still same error :(

**TEMPORARILY FIX**
add this to line 1496 of wsdl.js file of node-soap :

```
name = 'ns1:'+name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
var options = {
    overrideRootElement: {
        namespace: 'ns1'
    }
};
```

It works on version 0.16

Answer (score 2):

Had the same Problem with Version 0.14.0 of node-soap.
Switching back to 0.11.0 solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.16.0 the suggested solution of resetting the `ignoredNamespaces` works again:

```
var options = {
  ignoredNamespaces: {
    namespaces: [],
    override: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 0.16.0 you should change line 1530:

```
WSDL.prototype.objectToDocumentXML = function(name, params, nsPrefix, nsURI, type) {
   var args = {};
   args["ns1:" + name] = params; // instead of args[name] = params;
   ...
```